# SQL query I dont understand

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql query that will produce 100 000 rows in table `superstatistics_counter`. 
I have found this on internet, but it is magic for me. I have basic undrestanding of SQL queries (I know how insert and select works), but not like this. I googled but it is still unclear to me...

What does statements in parentheses mean? What does `t`, `t2`, ... mean? @row?

```
INSERT INTO superstatistics_counter(nid, totalcount, daycount,timestamp) SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, 100, 50, NOW() FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t5, 
(SELECT @row:=0) t6
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's doing a `CROSS JOIN` via an implicit `JOIN` syntax (`,` in the `FROM` clause).  It's essentially getting the cartesan product of all of the sub-select statements, resulting in all of the numbers from 0 - 99,999.  The `t#` are just the aliases for each of the sub-selects.

Comment: t is simply referring to them as transaction numbers

Comment: t, t2, etc are alias to name what's inside the parentheses. @ is used to name variables in MySql.

Answer (score 2):

Last line `(SELECT @row:=0) t6` intializes a variable @row to 0 and then a loop `@row := @row + 1` at first line increases it by 1 each time. 
`t` to `t5` are cross joined, each having 10 rows each. So generating 10*10*10*10*10 = 100000 rows.
100000 rows getting id's from 1 to 100000 from `@row`.

Answer (score 0):

The select 0 to 9 in each line creates 10 records for each column. So you have 5 columns(they are aliased as t,t2,t3,t4,t5 respectively) with value from 0 to 9. And it is cross joined creating 100,000 records.

And we define variables using @.

@row := @row + 1 is running as a loop with +1 increment.